# Can't import global package (opencv) when pipenv shell activated

Tags: python, opencv, pipenv

I've installed opencv via brew with the following:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3
```

and changed bindings:

```
 echo /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python3.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/opencv.pth
```

In normal python shell I can `import cv2` just fine, but when I'm in a new pipenv shell I can't seem to import cv2 anymore. Why?

Comment: You also have to make the package known to the new virtual environment. So practically the same you did for the default python but now point to the pipenv.

Comment: any idea how I do that?

Comment: Try `echo /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/python3.7/site-packages >> /path/to/pipenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/opencv.pth`. You can find the path of your virtual environment by first switching to it (via `source activate env_name`) and afterwards using `which python`. This will print the path of the python currently in use to your screen and you can alter your `echo` command accordingly.

Comment: Ah sorry, I just realized you are using pipenv, sorry. Here you can do `pipenv run which python` to get the path to the python and use that in your `echo` command. The approach I was describing in my previous comment is the more generic one for virtual environments.

Comment: got it working now. cheers!